# What is the difference between the below sample codes in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

What is the difference between the two sample codes below the second returns an error I don't know why

```
@if ( auth()->check() )
Welcome  {{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

and this

```
@if ( {{auth::check() }} )
Welcome  {{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Both are in a blade file. Please lets discuss this for better understanding. Also please indicate which is better to use in both scenarios

Comment: `{{}}` is used to show php content in html. You don't need to add `{{}}` in `@` directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do this:

```
@if ( {{auth::check() }} )
```

It will give you an error. It's almost the same as doing this:

```
if (echo(auth()->check()))
```

This code:

```
{{ auth()->check() }}
```

Will be converted to this vanilla PHP code:

```
<?php echo e(auth()->check()); ?>
```

Where [`e()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-e) is Laravel helper.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same, `@if ( auth()->check() )` will check if the user is authenticated or not.
And the other `@if ( {{auth::check() }} )` it's like what @Alexey said, will be converted to `<?php echo e(auth()->check()); ?>` and of course will return an error in your situation